# Error message: "Image.rename: The number of names must match the number of bands. Have 4, found 1."

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to estimate the VCI (Vegetation Condition Index) but I get the error message:

> Image.rename: The number of names must match the number of bands.  Have 4, found 1.

Any ideas? I think, the problem is at the final part of the script: "VCI CREATION"

Here is the Code Editor script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/008283891289f6d518058b2d9f2175c4

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `composite` image used in the mapped function to calculate the "VCI" index has four bands. You need to `.select('NDVI')` from it. The selected single band of NDVI from `img1` is being used as a numerator constant for the four bands of the `composite` image in the division step - four bands are returned.

This snippet corrects the problem:

```js
filtered = filtered.map(function(img1) {
  var vci = img1.select('NDVI')
                .subtract(minNDVI)
                .divide((composite.select('NDVI').subtract(minNDVI)))
                .multiply(100)
                .rename('vci');

  return img1.addBands([vci]);
});
```